# Why does this local font have "../../" in its source url?

Tags: css, font-face, src

This is the **src url** in a font-face for a local font in a wordpress theme. I can't for the life of me figure this out. Searching on google brings me no results.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Example";
    src: url("../../fonts/example.eot");
    src: url("../../fonts/example.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../fonts/example.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../../fonts/example.woff") format("woff"), url("../../fonts/example.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../../fonts/example.svg#Example") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: `../` means up one directory in a relative path. So `../../` would be two parent folders up before the rest of the path.

Comment: That is relative to the `css` file itself.

Comment: So technically I can use `../` all the way up to the font name? For example, instead of `src: url("../../fonts/example.eot")` I could use `src: url("../../../example.eot")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two dots like that in a relative url mean "up to next parent directory" and you can use this more than one time to climb ever higher in the directory structure.

If you had a folder tree like this:

```
A/
  B/
  C/
     - File In C Folder.css
  D/
      E/
      F/
         - File In F Folder.css
```

From the location of `File In F Folder.css` if you wanted to refer to the location of `File In C Folder.css` you would first walk "up" two levels to `A` and then back down to `C`.

So the path would be

```
../../C/File In C Folder.css
```

Comment: Is it more efficient performance-wise to use `../` as opposed to using the entire url? Example: `src: url("http://example.com/assets/local/fonts/example.eot")`

Comment: I don't think it has any effect on performance but people use relative ULRs like this to avoid having to hard code domain names. If your domain changes or you deploy a test version of your site having to do a find and replace on all absolute URLs  is a chore. If the URL is unlikely to change you can use the full, absolute path.